# Taylor expansion with integral?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, optimization, power-series

I have looked at a version of a Taylor expansion that has an integral- for the first time. Is this the same as the usual version of a Taylor expansion without integrals? Also, do the $\alpha's$ have something to do with the convexity/non-convexity of $g(.)$ and what is the significance of this formulation?

$g(Y)+(X-Y)^T\nabla g(Y) + (X-Y)^T\left[\int_0^1(1-\alpha)\nabla^2g(\alpha X + (1-\alpha)Y)d\alpha\right](X-Y)$

The only version of the Taylor expansion, I am instead aware of:

$g(Y) + (X-Y)^T\nabla g(Y)+ \frac{1}{2}(X-Y)^T \nabla^2(X-Y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fundamental theorem of calculus, we now
$$f(X) = f(Y) + \int_0^1 f'(\alpha \, X + (1-\alpha)\, Y) \, (X-Y) \, d\alpha.$$
Using this for $f = g$ and $f = g'$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
g(X) &= g(Y) + \int_0^1 g'(\alpha \, X + (1-\alpha) \, Y) \, (X-Y)\, d \alpha \\
&= g(Y) + \int_0^1 g'(Y)\,(X-Y) + \int_0^1 g''\Big(\tilde\alpha(\alpha \, X + (1-\alpha) \, Y) + (1-\tilde \alpha \, Y \Big) \, (X-Y)^2 \, d \tilde \alpha \, d \alpha \\
&=g(Y) + g'(Y) \, (X-Y) + \int_0^1 (1-\alpha) \, g''(\alpha \, X + (1-\alpha) \, Y ) \, (X-Y)^2 \, d \alpha
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you put in more explanation apart from the details you put forth to express $g(X)$?

Comment: What do you exactly mean? See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder

Comment: @gerw I know it's been a long time since you answered this post, but I have a question to make: Why is $\;f(X) = f(Y) + \int_0^1 f'(\alpha \, X + (1-\alpha)\, Y) \, (X-Y) \, d\alpha\;$ true? I only see this $\;f(X) = f(Y) + \int_0^1 f'(\alpha \, X + (1-\alpha)\, Y) \, \, d\alpha\;$ to be valid.

Comment: This follows with a linear substitution from $f(X) = f(Y) + \int_Y^X f'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$.